BERT embedding cosine similarities look very random and useless
I thought you can use BERT embeddings to determine semantic similarity. I was trying to group some words in categories using this, but the results were very bad.
E.g. here is a small example with animals and fruits. Notice that the highest similarity is between cat and banana?
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_hidden_states=True).eval()

def gen_embedding(word):
    encoding = tokenizer(word, return_tensors='pt')
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**encoding)

    token_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state.squeeze()
    token_embeddings = token_embeddings[1 : -1]
    word_embedding = token_embeddings.mean(dim=0)
    return word_embedding

words = [
    'cat',
    'seagull',
    'mango',
    'banana'
]

embs = [gen_embedding(word) for word in words]

print(cosine_similarity(embs))

# array([[1.        , 0.33929926, 0.7086487 , 0.79372996],
#        [0.33929926, 1.0000001 , 0.29915804, 0.4000572 ],
#        [0.7086487 , 0.29915804, 1.        , 0.7659105 ],
#        [0.79372996, 0.4000572 , 0.7659105 , 0.99999976]], dtype=float32)

Am I doing something wrong?

I think comments with tensor shape would be good (and those shape should be checked manually by you). 2 things that comes in my mind: the first token [CLS] for each input is supposed to be the sentence level representation. So use this, not the mean. Then, cosine similarity is interesting between tokens. I am very unsure about your mean and the omission of keepdim.

@MufasaChan I saw the use of mean in some tutorial. I guess it isn't that good? What do you mean by keepdim? "Then, cosine similarity is interesting between tokens." I thought this is a standard thing -- just like you can do with word2vec (except here I sometimes have multiword phrases).

Output the shape and it should be clearer. keepdim see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html, it would not remove the dimension 0. And cosine similarity is absolutely standard, it's no problem, it's how you measure the similarity between tokens, namely what you are looking for.The main point is that you should output the shape to be sure that you process something meaningful with the tensor computation.

I have tested that the shapes are correct. That is not the issue.
